# Plumbers putty - wrap the entire opening?

Tags: plumbing

The pipe in my bathroom sink has 2 large openings that I was not expecting.

Should I use plumbers putty and wrap the entire open holes, or just use plumbers putty around the drain in the sink? [image]

Comment: That sink drain is intended for use with a sink which has an overflow port. If your sink does not have an overflow then this is the wrong drain and you should return it and get the correct one instead. Trying to cover those holes is just asking for trouble of the wet kind.

Comment: @brhans that answers my question - post that and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sink drain is intended for use with a sink which has an overflow port.
If your sink does not have an overflow then this is the wrong drain and you should return it and get the correct one instead.
Trying to cover those holes is just asking for trouble of the wet kind.